# Detecting a plugin on Chrome using Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, python-3.x, browser-addons

I currently am trying to automate a process at my company (I am intern) and have the following done so far:

```
import webbrowser

command_center_url = 'http://docs.python.org/'

# MacOS
chrome_path = 'open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app %s'

# Windows
# chrome_path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %s'

# Linux
# chrome_path = '/usr/bin/google-chrome %s'

webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(command_center_url)
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open_new_tab(command_center_url)
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open_new_tab(command_center_url)
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open_new_tab(command_center_url)
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open_new_tab(command_center_url)
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open_new_tab(command_center_url)
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open_new_tab(command_center_url)
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open_new_tab(command_center_url)
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open_new_tab(command_center_url)
```

Now, I want to detect a certain plugin that Chrome has which would reposition this across multiple screens. Please advise how to go forward. Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT: Upon scanning the web for more answers, I've found Selium to be the best bet. However, as you can imagine I won't be able to load an external package (webdriver) due to security restrictions. Any way to do this the "old fashioned way?"